# MySQL index versus Sphinx index

Tags: mysql, indexing, sphinx

I have a question that , i use the index by the mysql database itself to index is better or using the index function in sphinx index.

Answer (score 1):

it depends.

sphinx is a better index by all standards but 1. it's faster, has a more advanced syntax, is smaller, is more scalable, doesn't involve myisam.

mysql is more maintainable, simpler to install, does not involve another tier to your application, and if it's good enough you might as well use it.

Comment: But I wish is just the field in the table exactly equal the query. Sphinx's matching is more complex.

Comment: exact match is easy. for that SQL is best. just index the field and use SQL.  SELECT * FROM foo WHERE field = "My Query";  or  SELECT * FROM foo WHERE field LIKE 'My Que%'   warning, if you put the % at the start of the LIKE match clause it'll do a table scan.

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx provides you full text search option. You can say its a mini search engine embedded in your app. And with no doubts its better Mysql Index.

If you just want to index auto incremented integer columns then there seems no point adding sphinx in your app. Still database size matters.

Checkout some the previously asked questions to get better idea what suits your needs.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sphinx?sort=votes

Comment: For example, I have 'name' filed in my table, I want to index it. When I look up the name, I need the name just equal the name I query. I use the index command by mysql itself,or by sphinx?

Comment: Go for sphinx in this case. Told u if you want to index only integer values then mysql is fine but if you are looking for indexing too much text then go for sphinx.